# Snowflake: Is it mandatory to return value from procedure?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-overview.html#returning-a-value-from-a-stored-procedure-is-optional

**Snowflake doc says**
A stored procedure is allowed to return a value, but is not required to return a value.

But in syntax RETURNS is mandatory.

```
CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] PROCEDURE <name> ( [ <arg_name> <arg_data_type> ] [ , ... ] )
  RETURNS <result_data_type> [ NOT NULL ]
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
  [ { CALLED ON NULL INPUT | { RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT | STRICT } } ]
  [ VOLATILE | IMMUTABLE ]
  [ COMMENT = '<string_literal>' ]
  [ EXECUTE AS { CALLER | OWNER } ]
  AS '<procedure_definition>'
```

Can someone explain how can we create a procedure without returning a value out of it or is it mandatory to return a value from procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to that syntax it is mandatory. But your returning value can be just static varchar and not coming from your query result. Or even NULL if you don't return anything from your procedure.

For example like this (returning NULL)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE testproc()
RETURNS varchar
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT AS
'var sqlcommand =
`INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES (999);`
snowflake.execute({sqlText: sqlcommand});
';
```

But it is better to add some error handling and return success / failure message, like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE testproc()
RETURNS varchar
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT AS
'var sqlcommand =
`INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES (999);`
try {
    snowflake.execute({sqlText: sqlcommand});
    return "Success";
    }
catch(err) {
    return "Failed: "+ err;
}
';
```

Comment: So it will be returning NUll?

Comment: My Example returns varchar "Done" if run succeeds and "Failed <error message here>" if it doesn't. But you can return NULL if you like.

Comment: @rakeshsingh I updated my answer. There was a few syntax problem. The one there is now is tested and it works. And it returns `NULL` and in procedure there is no `return` statement.

Comment: @ex4 may I suggest making your code more database agnostic and easier to reproduce? 

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE testproc()
RETURNS varchar
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT AS
'var sqlcommand =`SELECT 1 AS result;`
snowflake.execute({sqlText: sqlcommand});
';

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE testproc()
RETURNS varchar
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT AS
'var sqlcommand =`SELECT 1/0 AS result;`
try {
    snowflake.execute({sqlText: sqlcommand});
    return "Success";
    }
catch(err) {
    return "Failed: "+ err;
}';

Comment: @FrancescoQuaratino: Thank you for suggestion. I update the answer.....

Comment: I think @rakeshsingh was thinking can he use SQL query which doesn't return anything in his procedure. Such as INSERT or UPDATE. Your query returns 1, so it probably wouldn't answer his question.